# Using jQuery plugins on multiple targets and pages with similar configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have successfully configured a jQuery plugin as shown below (EDIT: Note that I am not asking anyone to review, just answer the specific question).  Now I need to do the same for different targets using an identical configuration object except for the ID name on line 4 (i.e. instead of `template1`, it might be `someOtherTemplateID`.

How can I do so without duplicating the code on each page?

My only thought is to create an object with everything passed to the plugin below, but also include an extra property called `template`.  Then, instead of hardcoding `var source = $("#template1").html();`, I would change it to `var source = $("#"+this.template).html();`  I would then set `myObj.template="someOtherTemplateID"`, and use the plugin as `$('a.linkPreview').ajaxTip(myObj);`.  This approach does not sound ideal, and I expect there is a cleaner way to do so.

```
$('a.linkPreview').ajaxTip({
    url:'index.php',
    display: function(d){
        var source = $("#template1").html();  //template1 needs to change to another ID 
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 
        Handlebars.registerHelper("formatPhoneNumber", function(p) {
            p = p.toString();
            return "(" + p.substr(0,3) + ") " + p.substr(3,3) + "-" + p.substr(6,4);
        });
        Handlebars.registerHelper('fullName', function(f,l) {
            return f + ((f&&l)?" ":"") + l;
        });
        Handlebars.registerHelper('specNumber', function(s) {
            return (s)?s.substr(0,2)+' '+s.substr(2,2)+' '+s.substr(4):'';
        });
        Handlebars.registerHelper('specNumberP', function(s) {
            return (s)?' ('+s.substr(0,2)+' '+s.substr(2,2)+' '+s.substr(4)+')':'';
        });
        return template(data);
    },
    getData:function(){
        var d=ayb.getUrlVars(this.attr('href'));
        d.task='getPopup';
        return d;
    }
});
```

The ajaxTip plugin is listed below.  Note that I don't believe is needed for my question.

```
/*
* jQuery ajaxTip
* Copyright Michael Reed, 2013
* Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
*/
(function($){
    var defaults = {
        'url'      : 'getAjaxTip.php', // The url used to get the tooltip data.
        'class'    : '', // Css class(es) to add to tooltip (along with standardAjaxTip).
        'mouseMove': true, // A flag indicating whether to move tooltip with mouse.
        'speed'    : 'fast', // The speed at which to fade in the tool tip.
        'delay'    : 250, // Delay (in ms) before requesting data from server.
        'xOffset'  : 20,
        'yOffset'  : 10,
        'dataType' : 'json',            
        'getData'  : function () {  //Use to set additional data to the server 
            return {}; 
        },
        // A function to transform the data from the server into an html fragment.
        'display'  : function(data) {   
            var htmlString = '';
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                htmlString += '<p>' + val + '</p>';
            });
            return htmlString;
        }
    };

    var methods = {
        init : function (options) {
            // Create settings using the defaults extended with any options provided.
            var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

            return this.each(function () {
                var title,
                    timeoutID,
                    ajax,
                    $t,
                    ajaxTip;

                // Wrap the content of the current element in a span.
                $t = $(this).wrapInner('<span />');

                $t.children('span').hover(function(e) {
                    if(!$t.hasClass('ajaxToolActive')) {
                        title = $t.attr('title');
                        $t.attr('title','');  // Remove the title so that it doesn't show on hover.

                        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {
                            ajax = $.get(settings.url, settings.getData.call($t), function (data) {
                                // Create a div to be the tooltip pop up, add the styling as well as
                                // the html (from the display function) to it and then fade the element in
                                // using the speed specified in the settings.
                                ajaxTip = $('<div />')
                                .addClass('standardAjaxTip ' + settings['class'])
                                .html(((title !== '') ? '<h3>' + title + '</h3>' : '') + settings.display.call($t,data))
                                .css('top', (e.pageY - settings.yOffset) + 'px')
                                .css('left', (e.pageX + settings.xOffset) + 'px')
                                .css('position', 'absolute')
                                .appendTo('body')
                                .fadeIn(settings.speed);

                                $t.addClass('ajaxToolActive');
                            }, 
                            settings.dataType);
                        }, settings.delay);
                    }
                },
                function () {
                    // User is no longer hovering so cancel the call to the server and hide the tooltip.
                    if (typeof ajax === 'object') { 
                        ajax.abort(); 
                    }
                    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
                    $t.attr('title', title);

                    if ($t.hasClass('ajaxToolActive')) {
                        ajaxTip.remove();
                        $t.removeClass('ajaxToolActive');
                    }
                });

                $t.mousemove(function (e) {
                    if (settings.mouseMove && $t.hasClass('ajaxToolActive')) {
                        ajaxTip.css('top', (e.pageY - settings.yOffset) + 'px')
                            .css('left', (e.pageX + settings.xOffset) + 'px');
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        destroy : function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $e = $(this);
                $e.html($e.children('span').html());
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.ajaxTip = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.ajaxTip');
        }    
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I have two questions. 1) A jQuery plugin must be set somewhere to the jQuery.prototype like `$.fn.ajaxTip = function() {/* ... */}`. How did you do that? 2) Object.display is a function with an argument `d` that's nowhere used. What is it for ?

Comment: @MartinErnst.  It is set to the jQuery.prototype just like you showed.  The plugin itself uses `d`.  While I don't think it is relevant, I will post the entire plugin as well.

Comment: I don't know that I'd include the template id variable in the options object. I'm not even sure if that would work. What about storing the template id in either a global variable or as a data attribute attached to your a.linkPreview element

Comment: @ClaytonLeis  THe data attribute seems like a good approach.  I don't, however, wish to modify the original plugin.  Instead, I want to make a new version of it which either accepts the ID, or as you suggest, use a data attribute.

Comment: I'm not saying modify the original plugin. You just need to change your "display" function right?

I'm saying change it to say `var source = $("#"+$(this).data('template')).html();`

Comment: @ClaytonLeis It would not work. The plugin internally calls `display()` with `settings.display.call($t, data)`. That sets the context (=`this`) to the internal `var $t` and `$(this).data()` wouldn't find anything.

Comment: @MartinErnst Right, just looking at the code, I believe $t is the original element.

Comment: @ClaytonLeis Thanks. Now I notice your older comment `...attached to your a.linkPreview element`. You are right, `$t` refers to that `a.linkPreview`. Since it's already a jQuery object, `this.data()` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try. You call it by $("selector").ajaxTip("templateIdHere");

```
(function($) {
    // add object to vars with a placeholder for target
    var defaultObject = {
        target: null, // the target later gets passed in here
        url: 'index.php',
        display: function(data, target) {
            var source = $('#' + target).html();
            /* ... */
        },
        /* ... */
    };

    /* ... */

    .html(((title !== '') ? '<h3>' + title + '</h3>' : '') + settings.display.call($t,data, settings.target))

    /* ... */

    $.fn.ajaxTip = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            /* ... */
        } else if (typeof method === 'string') {
             return methods.init.call(this, $.extend(defaultObject, {target: method}));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
            /* ... */
        } else {
            /* ... */
        }    
    };
}(jQuery));
```

There is one restriction: the global object `Handlebars` must be defined before this plugin.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  I will give this a try when I get home tonight.  Question:  Is it possible to do something similar, but not affect the original plugin source code, but somehow extend the plugin and make these changes?

Comment: @user1032531 Sorry, this is the only coming into my mind. The only hook the plugin provides for extension from outside is passing an object as argument, but even if the object has additional properties like `template` they won't be noticed inside the plugin. Even your thought of `var source = $("#"+this.template).html();` won't work: caused by the way `display()` is called `this` refers to the internal `var $t`.